# B2C Custom Policy with TP OpenId Connect - IdTokenAudience - MultiApple scenario

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a custom policy with an OpenId Connect Technical Profile calling authorize and token endpoints from metadata Items to my custom API middleware which is used to redirect to Apple authenticathion endpoint/website so i can handle a multiApple solution within my custom Policy trying to Ignore **client_id** and **IdTokenAudience**.
Microsoft documentation states:
[image]

**But unfortunatelly the documentation is wrong and the TokenAudience is always validated after get sucessfully the Apple token and return the flow to B2C** through the redirect_uri configured in Apple console for that clientId that I am able to pass through the Authorize endpoint in my API.

Can some B2C expert shed some light about ignore the IdTokenAudience in an OpenId Connect TP inside a Custom Policy?

Microsoft Reference document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect-technical-profile

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i will answer my question.
As stated by @Jas you cannot get rid of client_id because of security validations. So if someone is trying to implement such scenario, i will explain my approach:

1. Create a Technical Profile like this with client_id="myaudience" and use METADATA item to point to your custom OIDC microservice metadata. A B2C app clientId (B2C URL clientId) must be passed as input claim to handle diferent Apple client_id's depending on registered App:

   ```
     <TechnicalProfile Id="AppleID">
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io/metadata?provider=apple</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item> 
        <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">myaudience</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_MultiIDP" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groupId" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="appId" PartnerClaimType="clientId" DefaultValue="{OIDC:ClientId}" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="preferred_username" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="Apple user" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="picture" PartnerClaimType="picture" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="apple.com" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
   ```
2. Your custom multi-IDP microservice will capture in the /authorize endpoint via queryString the clientId and should retrieve from a storage the Apple client_id, teamId, redirect_uri (same than Apple console), KeyId and Issuer corresponding to it.
3. your /authorize should redirect to the Apple authentication page and will prompt for your credentials.
4. After enter credentials and click on "continue" button your /token endpoint should be fired, at this point you need to retrieve the .p8 secret (Private Key) from a Key Vault to generate the token to be used with the code in the /token body.
   The client_id, client_secret and keyId should be overrided with your custom stored data.

[image]

5. After craft the token and build the data to send to Apple /token endpoint, retrieve the Apple final token with its access_token, id_token, refresh_token ..

[image]

6. At this point you need to return all this data to B2C but the audience will fail, so you need to recraft a new id_token before passing the control to B2C through the configured redirect_uri, also you can move the Claims coming from Apple to the new forged token. The secret key used to sign the new token must be configured before as a Policy Key (signature) in your B2C Identity Experience Framewrok.
   Refer to this doc for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect-technical-profile
   This secret is referenced as cryptographickey in the Technical Profile above as: B2C_1A_MultiIDP

[image]

7. Return the data from your microservice /token endpoint to B2C:

[image]

Thats all! Happy coding!

Update Jun 2023:

Token Generator class:

```
public class TokenGenerator : ITokenGenerator
{
    private IConfiguration _config;
    public TokenGenerator(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
    public string GenerateGenericToken(string code, string issuer)
    {
        string newToken = string.Empty;

        Dictionary<string, object> claims = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        string sub = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        claims.Add("code", code);
        claims.Add("sub", sub);

        claims.Add("email", "dirty@gmail.com");
        claims.Add("email_verified", "true");
        claims.Add("auth_time", ((int)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds).ToString());
        newToken = GenerateToken(issuer, claims);
        return newToken;
    }

    public string GenerateToken(string issuer, Dictionary<string, object> claims)
    {
        var B2CEncodedPrivateKey = _config[ConfigParameter.B2CIDPPrivateSecret.ToString()];
        var mySecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(B2CEncodedPrivateKey));
        var myAudience = "MyTPB2CCLIENTID";
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        Dictionary<string, object> header = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        header.Add("kid", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        header.Add("kty", "oct");
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, claims["sub"].ToString())
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            Claims = claims,
            Issuer = issuer,
            Audience = myAudience,
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(mySecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
            AdditionalHeaderClaims = header

        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
}
```

Apple Service:

```
  public async Task<string> AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizeModelDTO authorizeModel)
        {
            _logger.LogEvent("GENERACION URI PROVIDER <APPLE>");
            string Uri = "";

            AppleClientData clientData = await _context.GetClientDataByProviderAsync(authorizeModel.clientId, authorizeModel.provider);

            Uri = GetAppleAuthorizeUri(authorizeModel.nonce, authorizeModel.state, clientData.TeamId, clientData.ProviderClientId, clientData.redirect_uri, authorizeModel.scope);
            //TODO: Check provider..
            _logger.LogEvent("FIN GENERACION URI PROVIDER <APPLE>");
            return Uri;
        }

        public Task<Dictionary<string, string>> CorrelateAsync(string provider, string code, string clientSecret)
        {
            _logger.LogEvent("GENERACION TOKEN GENERICO");

            Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();  
            if (_config[ConfigParameter.B2CIDPPrivateSecret.ToString()] == clientSecret)
            {
                string issuer = "";
                if (provider.ToLower() == "Apple".ToLower())
                    issuer = "https://appleid.apple.com";

                result.Add("access_token", code);
                result.Add("token_type", "code");
                result.Add("expires_in", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30).ToLongTimeString());
                result.Add("refresh_token", "fakerefrshtoken");
                result.Add("id_token", _tokenGenerator.GenerateGenericToken(code, issuer));
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add("error", "invalid client_secret");
            }
            _logger.LogEvent("FIN GENERACION TOKEN GENERICO");
            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }

        public async Task<TokenData> TokenAsync(string clientId, string code, string CorrelationId, string provider, string hostName)
        {
            _logger.LogEvent($"PETICION TOKEN A TRAVES DE CODE <{code}>");

            Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var finalContent = "";
            try
            {
                var prov = provider.ToLower();

                _logger.LogInformation("Buscamos informacion del cliente segun el proveedor");
                //GET cosmos
                AppleClientData clientData = await _context.GetClientDataByProviderAsync(clientId, provider);

                if (clientData != null)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("ENCONTRAMOS informacion del cliente segun el proveedor");

                    var appClientId = clientData.ProviderClientId.Replace(".", "");

                    _logger.LogInformation("BUSCAMOS KV Secret");

                    var kvSecret = _config[prov + "-" + appClientId].ToString();

                    if(kvSecret != null && kvSecret != "")
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation("ENCONTRAMOS KV Secret");
                        var secret = new CreateClientSecret
                        {
                            issuer = clientData.TeamId,
                            keyid = clientData.KeyId,
                            subject = clientData.ProviderClientId,
                            thumb = kvSecret
                        };

                        _logger.LogInformation("GENERAMOS Apple Token");

                        var secretToken = _appleTokenHandler.GenerateAppleToken(_config, "", secret);

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(secretToken))
                        {
                            _logger.LogInformation("GENERADO Apple Token");

                            
                            var data = _serviceAgent.GetAppleDataBody(clientData.ProviderClientId, secretToken, code, clientData.redirect_uri, CorrelationId);

                            _logger.LogInformation("LLAMADA a Apple /token");
                            finalContent = await _serviceAgent.GetAuthTokenApple(_config, data, "");

                            var r = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AppleToken>(finalContent);
                            if (r != null)
                            {
                                //Validamos token
                                if (await _tokenValidator.CheckToken(r.id_token))
                                {
                                    TokenData dataToReturn = _appleTokenHandler.DecodeAppleToken(r.id_token);
                                    _logger.LogInformation($"////TOKEN DATA RESULT :");
                                    _logger.LogInformation(dataToReturn.ToString());
                                    _logger.LogEvent($"EXITO FIN PETICION TOKEN A TRAVES DE CODE");
                                    return dataToReturn;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                _logger.LogEvent($"ERROR FIN PETICION TOKEN A TRAVES DE CODE");
                throw;
            }
            _logger.LogEvent($"SIN EXITO FIN PETICION TOKEN A TRAVES DE CODE");
            return null;
        }

        private string GetAppleAuthorizeUri(string nonce, string state, string teamId, string AppleclientId, string redirectUri, string scope)
        {
            return $"https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?client_id={AppleclientId}&redirect_uri={redirectUri}&response_type=code&scope={scope}&response_mode=form_post&nonce={nonce}&token_issuer={teamId}&state=StateProperties%3D{state}";
        }
```

Comment: You need to deal with the correlation between endpoints. If someone is interested i will update my answer.

Comment: Could you share more details about this implementation? In the end is it working properly?

I have a similar need, my application has multiple customers wanting to use external IDP's, I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to add one technical profile for each customer everytime.

Comment: Yes, it's working, The example is pointing to the right direction but i'm not sharing all details. You need to fool B2C returning a generic token with the same issuer declared in your Technical Profile "client_id". You need to correlate correctly in your custom policy TP /authorize and /token to your API adding a CorrelationId in your Input Claims.

Comment: Updated answer, Hope it helps a bit more. You can skip "METADATA" endpoint and use "authorize_endpoint" and "token_endpoint" in your TP.

Answer (score 1):

It’s being used as an override.

When this metadata item is not present, we make sure the audience matches the expected audience, client_id.

When it is specified, we make sure the aud claim matches what you state in the metadata item.

This never allows the verification to be turned off.

Comment: Thanks Jas. Do you mean the 'aud' claim must match with the client_id metada item when IdTokenAidience is not present? It has no sense and I would like to find a workaround for this problem. Thanks 

Comment: Your understanding is correct. I am not sure why you would not want this behaviour. Can you elaborate on the scenario?

Comment: Multitenancy, multiclient scenario to sign-in, signup with apple.